# 'This device could not be tested at this time. Please upload a new APK' after upload a aab

Tags: android, google-play-console

In the past, upload apks make everything ok.But now I'm trying to use app bundle to reduce my apk size.Something went wrong..
My step:

1. bundleFlavorRelease and got a aab in folder 'build/outputs/';
2. Upload to my google play console;
3. In pre-launch report menu,the resule shows only 'Galaxy S3 Samsung Android 4.3' has been test,others shows 'This device could not be
       tested at this time. Please upload a new APK'.

But when I use bundle tool to generate signed apks and install to my phones(Xiaomi redmi 4 and Huawei mate 20pro),everything works well..

Comment: You should reach out to Play Developer support so they can investigate.